# Is there an actively maintained mobile UI for Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, mobile-website

I'm using [Django Grappelli](http://grappelliproject.com/) as a skin for the Django admin interface. However, the design is not responsive. Users on mobile devices need to do a lot of zooming and panning. The mobile admin projects I've [found](http://code.google.com/p/django-jqmobile/) so far seem to have been [abandoned](https://github.com/jezdez/django-mobileadmin) in their early stages. Does anyone know of one that is actively maintained?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:
https://github.com/douglasmiranda/django-admin-bootstrap

It uses Bootstrap and is BSD licensed
[image: django-admin-bootstrap]

Comment: But it changes theme for pC's as well. is it possible to change theme only for mobile version?

Comment: It doesn't work with Django 1.9+

Answer (score 6):

Since version 1.9 Django uses a former third-party app called [django-flat-theme](https://github.com/elky/django-flat-theme/). There's another app made by the same developer which adds responsiveness to the admin. This app is called [django-flat-responsive](https://github.com/elky/django-flat-responsive).

That means, if you're on Django 1.9+ just add *django-flat-responsive*. If you're running an older version of Django you need *django-flat-theme* **and** *django-flat-responsive*.

As user [mirek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2520298/mirek) points out, all of this is already integrated into Django 2+.

This is what it looks like:

> [image: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CwuLWBlUUAAKqb3.jpg]

Comment: @Bashar is on point with his recommendation to use Django flat responsive which is the simplest way to go if you’re looking for a mobile friendly version of your Django admin UI. I created a video to show case the plugin in action you may have a look here [https://youtu.be/sxqZII3K8OU](https://youtu.be/sxqZII3K8OU) . You may also want to note things will get a bit weird if your mixing up this plugin with other theme apps.

Comment: I tagged the wrong user i meant to say you @jnns

Comment: flat-responsive is integrated into django 2+

Answer (score 1):

https://code.google.com/p/django-jqmobile/ and https://code.google.com/p/django-mobileadmin/ seems interesting too compared to the other one above

using jquerymobile is very light and benefits from html5 controls which looks like a native app when managing your django admin.

it could require some tweaks when it comes to other custom django apps to work properly with all functions of that app though.

Answer (score 1):

Django Jet is another responsive admin interface http://jet.geex-arts.com/

https://github.com/ 750+ stars

Comment: Django Jet is commercial now.